# The same entity is being tracked as different weak entity types

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following warning  using C#:

The same entity is being tracked as different weak entity types F.energyProfile2Schedule#EnergySlice' and 'F.energyProfile#EnergySlice'. If a property value changes, it will result in two store changes, which might not be the desired outcome.

[image: My domain]

How can I fix this problem, so in the future it does not result in two store changes ?

Comment: Hello Tiago; Did you find a solution for your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have a single instance of that "weak entity type", assigned as a property to two different entities.

Solution would be to not just assign this single instance of `EnergySlice` to `energyProfile2Schedule` and to `energyProfile`, but to create another instance of `EnergySlice` for second object.